# Prepare an SQL statement to get a safe query string, not using preparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sanitization

I have a query I want to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo LIKE <user_input>
```

I'm using a JDBC wrapper (custom made by someone else) that doesn't yet support `Connection.prepareStatement()`. I **have** to use this wrapper, so `prepareStatement()` is not an option.

I want to be able to prepare the query above so that it is robust to malicious user input, but I can't do it using `Connection.prepareStatement()` - I'd like to prepare it using something else, e.g.

```
String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo LIKE ?"
String preparedQuery = prepareSQL(sqlStatement, userInputString);
```

So that I can pass `preparedQuery` to

```
Statement statement = Connection.createStatement();
ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(preparedQuery);
```

Is there a way to do this? (Preferred: a built-in Java way?)

Comment: there are no method `executeQuery()` in `Connection` can you explain more i don't get you, and it can be better if you share your code

Comment: If you **have** to use the wrapper made by someone else, then have them fix their wrapper. Don't promulgate bad code just because they are clueless.

Comment: *"Is there a way to do this?"* Yes, but not a built-in Java way. You have to write method to correctly *escape* the inserted string literal.

Comment: @YCF_L updated to fix that mistake

Comment: This is a good example of why re-inventing the wheel by creating your own wrappers libraries etc. is a bad idea.

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver does it expose any method to get the underlying `java.sql.connection` instance?

Comment: Apache Commons Lang has [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeSQL()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql(java.lang.String)), which helps you handle single quotes.

Comment: There is no built-in way yet, JDBC 4.3 (Java 9) introduces [`Statement.enquoteLiteral`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#enquoteLiteral-java.lang.String-) which will _"Returns a `String` enclosed in single quotes. Any occurrence of a single quote within the string will be replaced by two single quotes. "_